# How to trigger iframe post from parent click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, iframe, jquery-file-upload

I am using Jquery multiple file upload control to upload the multiple files. It is very good plug in, All  operations are working fine.

I want to load that plug in iframe and i should trigger the global start post back method from parent window

Following is my sample code

LibraryDocs.aspx(parent interface)

```
> <iframe style="width: 90%; height: 300px" id="multipleFileUploadFrame"
> src="../Secure/MultipleFileUpload.htm" runat="server" />

> <asp:Button ID="postCompleteButton" runat="server" Text="Post Complete" />
```

Here is my MultipleFileUpload.htm

```
<div id="fileupload">
        <form id="multipleUpload" action="../Secure/MultipleUploadHandler.ashx" method="POST"
        enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="fileupload-buttonbar">
            <label class="fileinput-button">
                <span>Add files...</span>
                <input id="file" type="file" name="files[]" multiple />
            </label>
            <button id="startUpload" type="submit" class="start">
                Start upload</button>
            <button type="reset" class="cancel">
                Cancel upload</button>
            <!--<button type="button" class="delete">Delete files</button>-->

        </div>
        </form>
        <div class="fileupload-content">
            <table class="files">
            </table>
            <div class="fileupload-progressbar">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So my problem is after clicking postCompleteButton button in parent window it should fire the post event(start button) in child window which is in iframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using jQuery, you can access the iframe DOM using

```
$('#<%= multipleFileUploadFrame.ClientID %>').contents()
```

With this in mind, to click the Start upload button in the iframe, use

```
$('#<%= multipleFileUploadFrame.ClientID %>').contents().find('#startUpload').click();
```

Please keep in mind that this will only work if the parent and iframe source is on the same domain as the browser will adhere to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Answer (score 1):

If both pages are in the same origin, you can reffer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/invoking-javascript-in-iframe-from-parent-page?rq=1), otherwise use library like easyXDM (http://easyxdm.net/wp/). It will allow you to exchange messages or setup remote procedure calls between the iframe and the container windows. Check this page from the documentation - [remote procedure calls](http://easyxdm.net/wp/2010/03/17/remote-procedure-calls-rpc/)

Comment: Thax dobrinov for your response, I tried to do this, Since it is in same origin i used the first method, But unfortunately it didn't work for me. Isn't there any Jquery solution for this rather than using javascript.